# Insert page break into a PDF file

Tags: pdf

There is a given PDF file, in which I would like to insert only one page break to a page. I have tried to use `Nitro PDF` to convert it to `MS Word`, insert page break and convert it back, but it makes a lot of mistakes during conversion. Also same problem with `Foxit` softwares. Is there any easier way/advanced editor to insert a page break to a PDF file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option would be to use something like Adobe Acrobat or Foxit PhantomPDF (disclosure: I work for Foxit) to create a new, blank page after your target page X, which I will call Page X+1. Then cut and paste the objects from the bottom half of page X to page X+1.

I don't know of any PDF software that has an option to directly split pages.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't. PDF doesn't work that way - it isn't "flowing" text like MS Word, where you can insert a page break and it reflows the text. Think of PDF's as a picture of the text. It has a page, it has instructions on where on the page to put the blocks of text. Each page is an entity to itself, the pages have no idea that other pages exist.

The best you could do is to export the PDF as you have already, fix the results as best you can, then re-convert it back to a PDF.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. I plan to make however many new pages I need in the same document, paste the desired text into each, and delete the page(s) that aren't the way I want them. However, some pages have images and those ones I think this option won't work so I will still probably have a problem with those ones.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1177768)