# How to split a PDF page into 2 pages?

Tags: pdf

how do I split a PDF page into two pages. And put space after each half

In other words, I need this page:

```
[ AAA ]                < 1st page (page no.1)
[ BBB ]                < 1st page (page no.1)
```

to become like this:

```
[ AAA  ]               < 1st page (page no.1)
[ blank]               < 1st page (page no.1)

[ BBB  ]               < 2nd page (page no.2)
[ blank]               < 2nd page (page no.2)
```

- Also, I want to be able to remove some pages and residuals;
- I also need the result to be fit for printing.

Please help!

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool supporting it. Snipping tool?

Comment: I also need to be fit for printing

Comment: The blanks will be there automatically if you simply move the BBB piece to a new page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert page break into a PDF file](https://superuser.com/questions/986733/insert-page-break-into-a-pdf-file)

Comment: @user90327 These links may be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183479/cropping-a-pdf-using-ghostscript-9-01 https://www.grenadeco.com/tutorial/introduction-to-ghostscript/ it's definitely possible but would make quite a long superuser answer!

Answer (score 0):

**MAJOR EDIT:**

The only way to modify a PDF in the way you want, cutting a single page in half, is to either use a PDF modification application such as Adobe Acrobat Professional and copy the content in the way you want, or to take screenshots, which are perfectly capable of creating print-quality work, provided you use them carefully

**OLD INFORMATION, NOT VALID:**

Most PDF editing applications offer this.

The cheapest way to do this is to install a PDF Printer (If you have Windows 8 or 10, there is one built-in called "Microsoft Print to PDF") and then printing the first page of the PDF to this PDF printer, and then the second page, creating two separate documents. Adding a second blank page would require more steps but is probably doable.

You can also use a tool such as [PDF Split & Merge](https://pdfsam.org/download-pdfsam-basic/) (PDF SAM) which has built-in split and merge functions and is quite simple to use and has a free version which I have personally used for some time. First you'd create a PDF of a blank page using a PDF Printer such as in the 1st option above. Then you use PDF SAM's  split function to split your PDF into two pages. Then you'd use PDF SAM's merge function to add the blank page you created first to each of the 2 PDFs you created using the split function.

So the entire process would look like this:

1. Open your document editor and create a new blank document.
2. Print this document using the PDF printer on your computer. Save it as BlankPage.pdf.
3. Open the 2-page PDF using PDF SAM and split this by individual pages into pg1.pdf and pg2.pdf.
4. Open pg1.pdf in PDF SAM and use the merge function to add BlankPage.pdf as the second page.
5. Repeat step 4 using pg2.pdf.

Comment: I don't want to put a blank page after a book page. I want to put half a page of book then the rest of the page blank. Or did I understand you wrongly?

Comment: I'll try what you mentioned as "PDF Split & Merge"

Comment: I reread your answer. As I said, this isn't what I want

Comment: Oh, yes, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: This looks to have been previously addressed.  https://superuser.com/questions/986733/insert-page-break-into-a-pdf-file

Answer (score 0):

The function is a variation on "poster" printing  where a big page is split into smaller parts, thus it will be a two pass process to print the half pages into a new file and then increase the page to provide the blank half of each "poster" page.

Several tools can split a PDF for posters, Acrobat is perhaps best, as it allows fine control but if half page is all you need then here is a simple one line method for Part 1.
`mupdf\1.20.0>mutool poster -x 0 -y 2 SplitPDFpageIn2.pdf splitPDF.pdf`

[image]

Note a GOOD splitter should keep split text (no such thing) on both pages (as seen here) but NOT duplicate the other body text, which often happens when pages are copied and half trimmed out of view.

[image]

Part 2 of placing on top of fresh  page is a "Merge by Stamp" command onto blanks, however MuTool as far as I know, does not offer an easy way to do that. Nor can I see how to use cPDF except by add blank same size half pages throughout, then do a 2-UP to put the blank under the poster.

So at this point you could take the landscape A5 and Print to A4 Portrait at 100% scale, again should be easy in Acrobat. OR use a Programmable printer like GhostScript but beware some content like annotations may not always be carried over.

So I suggest look at redefining Pages Sizes (retaining contents) with cPDF or qPDF or simple free use PDFcpu, NOTE: I forgot to switch the top boundary off, which is an optional switch, and Hyperlinks are NOT retained currently in PDFcpu N-UP (they were there in the split file).

`pdfcpu page insert -mode after splitPDF.pdf padded.pdf`
`pdfcpu nup -- "form:A4P" outtop.pdf 2 padded.pdf`

[image]